# Update to 14.04 pushed on Sept 23 breaks X

Tags: 14.04, updates, xorg

This is on a Thinkpad W510.
Kernel is 3.13.0-36-generic pushed on Sept.3

Today's update required a reboot, after which the system boots,but X fails, displaying console login prompt for a few seconds, finally leaving a black,unresponsive screen. Failsafe grapics mode also fails the same way.

I've been poking around from a console login

The update left me without a /etc/X/xorg.conf, so I copied the last good one. This eliminated some error messages, but left X trying  to fi d an appropriate driver module.  It succesively tried, and failed for "nvidia", "fbdev", and vesa.

I'd done some CUDA development on this machine in the past, so I had been using a driver from Nvidia, which I may try reinstalling.

Suggestions?

Comment: Well, you could file a bug report on https://launchpad.net. [How do I report a bug?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug)

Comment: re-installing sounds like a really good idea because installation usually generates a file for "/etc/X/xorg.conf". When you remove the driver, use the command `sudo apt-get purge` followed by the package name(s), to remove all the config files also, rather than `sudo apt-get remove`. To show all installed packages related to nvidia, run the command `dpkg -l | grep nvidia`.

Answer (score 0):

Got this problem too, upon updating. Got a nasty segfault from X, and both regular and "safe" graphics mode failed to start X.

As a temporary workaround - I booted from the older 3.13.0-34 kernel and it worked fine (at boot time, via grub menu).

Updating to the latest nvidia driver in the "additional drivers" menu solved the issue (with 3.13.0-36, the latest kernel). I had nvidia binary driver 304.117, and moving to 331.38 made it work.